# while setting css property table tr :nth-child(1) { display: none; } all input elements in other tr childs are disappearing

Tags: html, css

```
table tr :nth-child(1) {
    display:    none;
}

<table class="tableForm">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Tax</th>
    <th>Agent Rate</th>
    <th>Counter Rate</th>
    <th>M.R.P.</th>                 
    <th></th>
</tr>           
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>12.50%</td>
    <td>120.16</td>
    <td>224.30</td>
    <td>27.30</td>
    <td class="clickCell" onClick="handleCellClick(this)">Update</td></tr>
</table>
</code>
```

Problem While setting style to first column of each row by css is table tr: nth-child(1)
it hides all  elements in other columens

please guide on this

Comment: what you want to hide?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. It works I have table having price list of products. in that i have fields are |id|product name|tax|agent rate |counter rate|mrp|. and i wanted to hide id field from user. i struggled 4 to 5 hrs and finally asked this query. i am glad and satisfied with your answer. you saved my time thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hide each **first** element, eg. text input too. But not all elements as you wrote.

If you want to hide just first TD, use

```
table tr td:nth-child(1)
```

or

```
table tr td:first-child
```

If you want to hide first TD/TH, use

```
table tr > *:nth-child(1)
```

or

```
table tr > *:first-child
```